# Using formulas in R

Tags: r, cran

It is possible to introduce a formula in R, and use this formula in a function to calculate a given parameter?  For example, imagine that we know that 3 variables show this relationship:

y^z/sqrt(x+z) = 0

How to create a function to provide data for two parameters (eg. x and y), and calculate the third?

```
funZ<-function(x, y){
    myform<- 0 ~ y^z/sqrt(x+z)
  abc<- ???
  return(abc)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will be a hard problem.  For example, if `x=1` and `y=2`, there's no solution: the expression `y^z/sqrt(x+z)` is positive for all `z` values where it is defined.  But in general, this is an approach you can use:

1. Instead of using a formula, use a function of 3 variables.  (You could use a formula, it just makes everything more complicated).  E.g.

```
    f <- function(x, y, z) y^z/sqrt(x+z)
```

2. Create a function of `z` within your `funZ`, and use `uniroot` to solve the
   equation:

```
    funZ <- function(x, y, interval) {
      fz <- function(z) f(x, y, z)
      uniroot(fz, interval)$root
    }
```

This assumes two things:

1. `x` and `y` are scalars.  If you want it to work for vectors, you'll need to loop over their values.
2. You know `interval` such that `f(x, y, interval[1])` has the opposite sign to `f(x, y, interval[2])`.  If you can't specify `interval`, then `uniroot` won't know where to look.